# How do I invalidate a bad authentication cookie early in the request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, .aspxauth

## Scenario

I develop an MVC application that will be hosted in Windows Azure.  During development, I test against a local database and local user membership service.  In production, the application hits off a SQL Azure database and a cloud-hosted user membership service.

Sometimes I'll log in to the *local* version of the site with a user account that *only* exists on my local machine.  If I forget to log out but switch my machine out of test mode, things start to break.

## The Problem

I set my `hosts` file to point my application URL at `127.255.0.0` so that browser requests are handled by the Azure emulator locally.  This also means my test application and the production application use the same host name - cookies for one are seen as valid cookies for the other.

If I log in to my local system, an `ASPXAUTH` cookie is created for the domain and contains the credentials of the user from my local system.  If I forget to log out and switch my `hosts` file back to normal (browser requests go to the live application), it sends the same `ASPXAUTH` cookie to the server.

Since this user doesn't exist on the server, only locally, any requests like `Membership.GetUser().Email` return an object null exception.

## What I'd Like to Do

Ideally, I could inject some code early in the request to check that the user exists.  Something like:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
if(user == null) {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

This will automatically remove the `ASPXAUTH` cookie for invalid users.  But where do I put it?  I started looking at my controllers - all of them inherit from a `BaseController` class, but even putting this code in the base controller's constructor isn't early enough.  I also looked at `Global.asax`, but I'm not sure which event would be best to tie this action to.

Also, I'm not even sure this is the right way to do things.  If not, what is the best way to ensure that the authentication cookie is for a valid user before just depending on the membership class like I am currently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may handle the below event in you global.aspx:

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
{ 
}
```

**EDIT:**

In the [above method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationeventhandler.aspx), `Membership.GetUser()` will return `null`, since it takes the userName from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` property and in this event the user has not yet been authenticated. The above method is invoked by [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.aspx) when it raised [Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate.aspx) even. You can handle this event like so:

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported &&
            Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var formsAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(formsAuthTicket.Name);
            if (user == null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO:log ex
        }
    }
}
```

You can also consider to handle the [AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) event by declaring the below method in the global.aspx.

NOTE: **Application_AuthenticateRequest** event is fired after the **FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate** event.

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {                
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        if (user == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.User = null;
        }
    }            
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: That won't work.  Placing my code from above (the `Membership.GetUser()` part) results in an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.  In the stack trace, it attempts to call `System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName()` and throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You create a base controller that overrides the `OnActionExecuting` and place your code there. 
Have all your controller controllers inherit from him. This the  `OnActionExecuting` from a older project I had

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (Session[SomeKey] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "LogOff" } });
        }
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

I'm basically checking if the request is authenticated otherwise I redirect it to logout action.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx